# Sending notifications / requests to application users (Facebook - C#)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-requests

Title may not describe what I actually want, but I hope this is not a duplicate question as I couldn't find a relevant answer in my searches.

I'm developing a Facebook raid manager application for my own World of Warcraft guild and what I want it to do is:

- When an officer creates a raid, send notifications (or app requests) to all application users whether they are friends of the officer or not.
- This request can be a user-to-user or app-to-user request, the only important thing is it must trigger a notification on Facebook side.

Again, to be clear, I'm not trying to send application requests to non-application users. I just want a way to send requests to application users triggered by a user event.

Application already has a "Facebook Group" authorization, which means all app users are members of a specific facebook group (not a page).

Is this possible via Facebook dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some rough code to send an app request using the C# SDK:

```
private string getAppAccessToken()
{
    string facebookAppId = ConfigurationProvider.GetSetting("FacebookAppId");
    string facebookAppSecret = ConfigurationProvider.GetSetting("FacebookAppSecret");
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
        String.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}",
        facebookAppId, facebookAppSecret));
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    var responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

    if (responseString.Contains("access_token="))
    {
        return responseString.Replace("access_token=", string.Empty);
    }

    return "";
}

private void postRequest(string id, string message)
{
    FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(this.getAppAccessToken());
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.message = message;
    parameters.title = "Please use our app";
    dynamic myId = app.Post(id + "/apprequests", parameters);
}
```

The notification should appear under App Center / Requests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped me a lot to figure out how apprequests sent. Thank you.

Comment: Can be used this for sending notifications?